# table localization

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm developing an web application that will be available in two languages and more languages could be added in the future.

I was designing the tables and I found a problem; Here's the structure:

```
Table: Tag;
Columns: TagId (PK)  {this column it's referenced by other tables like Posts, Users, etc...}

Table: TagLocale
Columns: TagLocaleId (PK), TagId(FK), LanguageId (FK), Name (the tag string)
```

It's wrong having a table with only one column, right? 
Anyone could help me here?

Thanks in advance,

Renan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly OK to have a table with only one column.

It means "this tag does exist".

It will come in very handy when you'll be building tag statistics (given that `MySQL` does not support full joins).

Answer (score 1):

Its perfectly fine to have a table with only one column.  The table is being used to constrain other table and serves as a reference to validate data.  often a single row reference table is populated first for data validation and reference.